# Accessible star rating for Android

Tags: android, accessibility

I recently included the RatingBar view into a layout and realized it is not compatible with Talkback (it is not accessible). How can I have a star rating view that takes into account Talkback users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example of what I need here:

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/2017/lib/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/CustomRatingBar.java

Comment: The Github link is down. It would be great if you could write down the solution that you came up with. The link-only answers are often dangerous as the link might get changed or removed. Thanks!

Comment: Updated link - https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/2017/lib/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/CustomRatingBar.java

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas for anyone else who ends up here.  I'm using targetSdk=28 and the androidx libraries.

**Problem 1:** Talkback skips the RatingBar when announcing the content in a ViewGroup.

Solution: Add a TextView with the desired announcement.  Make it 0dp, so it won't affect your layout.  INVISIBLE or GONE won't work.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="4.1 of 5 stars"/>
```

Solution: Display the number of ratings, and add the stars to the contentDescription.  (do it programmatically, though)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ratingCountTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="23"
    android:contentDescription="4.1 of 5 stars from 23 users"/>
```

**Problem 2:** Tapping on a RatingBar to hear the value.  contentDescription works in this case, and you can set it in code.

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:contentDescription="4.1 of 5 stars"/>
```

Tapping and dragging on a RatingBar to change the value seems to work.  It says 20%, 40%, 60%.